# update-grub2 creates config for wrong boot hdd

Tags: grub2, 16.04

My 16.04 runs with 3 SSDs/HDD. Ubuntu recognizes its own SSD as /dev/sdc and I guess therefore creates my `/boot/grub/grub.cnf` with `update-grub2` as follows:

```
set root='hd2,msdos5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd2,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd2,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci2,msdos5  66754cf8-aeb2-4eeb-a799-c4641cda0065
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 66754cf8-aeb2-4eeb-a799-c4641cda0065
fi
```

But when I'm booting the system, I need to manually change all the `hd2`s into `hd0` in grub for Ubuntu to boot, otherwise it cannot find the rootfs. I guess the problems are here since the upgrade from 14.04, but since I don't use this computer as much, I'm not sure exactly.

My `/etc/defaults/grub` should be unchanged as far as I remember:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Any idea what might be wrong? (I might be slow in testing stuff, since I don't have access to this machine all the time, but all answers are appreciated!)

Edit: It was on both SSDs, even though there is an old Windows installation on the other SSD. I of course checked if my changes in /boot/grub affected it, but both grubs seem to be using the config. Long story short, thanks to the commen from @Dorian, I changed the boot order in the bios and it works now.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?  Can you confirm that grub is installed on the drive that is set to boot first?

Comment: Thanks, it was really the wrong grub, edited question accordingly.

Comment: Great!  I can post an answer that you can accept so that you don't leave the question hanging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it, grub is installed on a disk/partition that isn't set to boot.  Or it may be installed on multiple drives.

Run `sudo fdisk -l` to list all your partitions and see which one is set to boot.

You have 2 options.

1) You can change your BIOS boot order, so that your computer boots into the correct GRUB that Linux is using.
2) Or, you can install Grub to the correct drive that is set to boot first by doing `sudo grub-install /dev/sdx` where X is your drive that is set to boot in your BIOS.